# jquery rotate function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

Hi guys at the moment i am trying to figure out how to rotate a div and make it stop at a loctation. I have had some help on this however iam not sure what iam doing wrong. Any help with the code would be great.

Thanks guys for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try change your javascript code to be like this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
var $elie = $("#super");
rotate(1);

function rotate(degree) {
$elie.css({
'-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
'-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
'-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
'-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
'transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'
});
console.log(degree);
if (degree < 100) {
timer = setTimeout(function() {
    rotate(++degree)
}, 1);
}} 
});
```

Here the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ongisnade/mq8Ar/

Answer (score 1):

Look at here http://jsbin.com/uwunaw/4/edit

I'm adding  `var elie = null;` as global var and put `elie = $("#super");` in onReady of jQuery.

*Like this*

```
$(function () {
    elie = $("#super");
    rotate(1);
});
```

It's working now.